# Xmlelement condition to get value of another element using c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i have an xmldoc with multiple records.
eg:

```
<value>
<id>aaaaa</id>
<condition>true</condition>
</value>

<value>
<id>bbbb</id>
<condition>false</condition>
</value>

<value>
<id>ccccc</id>
<condition>true</condition>
</value>
```

now using c# and xml linq
i need to check the condition element value's
if it is true then i need to pass its id value to string

code i used :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\Downloads\file.xml");

XmlElement xml= doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList cond= xml.SelectNodes("/value/condition");
XmlNodeList id= xml.SelectNodes("/value/id");

foreach (XmlElement node in cond)
{
    var value = node.InnerText;

    if (value == "true")
    {
        var id_values = id.InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(id_values);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

in this code im not able to get id value of condition which is true. it returns all id's but i need only id value which is against true condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the "value" nodes and analyze then in your loop. For example to get you started:

```
var s = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf - 8""?>
<values>
<value>
<id>aaaaa</id>
<condition>true</condition>
</value>

<value>
<id>bbbb</id>
<condition>false</condition>
</value>

<value>
<id>ccccc</id>
<condition>true</condition>
</value>
</values>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(s);

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/values/value");
foreach (XmlElement node in nodes)
{
    if (node.SelectSingleNode("condition").InnerText == "true")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText); // prints "aaaaa" and "ccccc"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the basics of [linq to xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview). It has number of apis for easy navigaton.

```
XElement.Load("file")
   .Elements(XName.Get("value"))
   .Where(x => x.Element("condition").Value.Equals(bool.TrueString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   .Select(x => x.Element("id").Value);
```